# animating UIView transitions like expand dot to circle

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewanimationtransition

In my iPhone app i need to implement a different type of transition.

that was

next view open from the current view,

it stats like a dot, and the dot expands slowly like a circle with in the circle next view is to be displayed partially with in the part of the circle , finally the circle expands totally the next view appears completely.

I search lots of transitions like CATransitions, and some animations on cocoa controller, but i didn't find this type of transition, can any one help me please.

[image][image][image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my case I did it that way:

set a `CAShapeLayer` instance as the layer's mask property of your custom view subclass

```
@interface MyCustomView ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) CircleShapeLayer *circleShapeLayer;
@end

@implementation MyCustomView

- (id) initWithFrame: (CGRect) frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame: CGRectZero];
    if (self) {
        self.layer.mask = self.shapeLayer;
        [self.layer.mask setValue: @(0) forKeyPath: @"transform.scale"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

zoom this mask layer to fullsize. code of your view:

```
- (void) zoom {
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath: @"transform.scale"];
    animation.fromValue = [self.layer.mask valueForKeyPath: @"transform.scale"];
    animation.toValue = @(1);
    animation.duration = 2.0;
    animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    animation.delegate = self;
    // Important: change the actual layer property before installing the animation.
    [self.layer.mask setValue: animation.toValue forKeyPath: animation.keyPath];
    // Now install the explicit animation, overriding the implicit animation.
    [self.layer.mask addAnimation: animation forKey: animation.keyPath];
    return;
}

- (CAShapeLayer *) circleShapeLayer {
    if (!_ circleShapeLayer) {
        _circleShapeLayer = [SGMaskLayer layer];
        _circleShapeLayer.delegate = _shapeLayer;
        _circleShapeLayer.frame = self.bounds;
        _circleShapeLayer.needsDisplayOnBoundsChange = YES;
    }

    return _circleShapeLayer;
}

@end
```

the code of the mask layer:

```
@interface CircleShapeLayer : CAShapeLayer
@end

@implementation CircleShapeLayer

- (void) drawLayer: (CALayer *) layer inContext: (CGContextRef) ctx {
    UIGraphicsPushContext(ctx);
    UIBezierPath *circlePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect: self.bounds];
    self.path = circlePath.CGPath;
    UIGraphicsPopContext();
}

@end
```

from the documentation:

> The layer’s alpha channel determines how much of the layer’s content
>   and background shows through. Fully or partially opaque pixels allow
>   the underlying content to show through but fully transparent pixels
>   block that content.
>
> The default value of this property is nil nil. When configuring a
>   mask, remember to set the size and position of the mask layer to
>   ensure it is aligned properly with the layer it masks.

so I drew a circle with UIBezierPath to achieve the round mask. at the beginning I set the mask's scale factor to 0 so nothing of the view's layer is visible. then the scale factor is set to 1 (filling the layer's bounds) animated which gives a nice animation of a circle increasing it's radius from the center.

you might need one more animation shifting the center point of your view. both animations can be wrapped in a CAAnimationGroup.

Comment: i think it may help, but be some clarity please

Comment: @hacker2007 Can you please tell me some more details about "myView" , "self.shapeLayer" and "self.layer"?

Answer (score 2):

Well I think I can offer you a workaround. Instead of pushing to the next view like a dot . I suggest you add a simple dot animation in the `ViewWillAppear` of the view in which you have to get pushed. Now the push method would remain the same like

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:NewView animated:YES];
```

But in the `ViewWillAppear` the code would be such that the dot would expand to a circle and reveal the New View beneath it. Hope you understand the logic I am trying to explain here. Any issue do let me know .

Comment: is there any way to get round animation

Answer (score 1):

**Open in first view:**

//Delegate method for annotation did select
    - (void)tapOnAnnotation:(RMAnnotation *)annotation onMap:(RMMapView *)map;
    {
        //To get the touch point of the GMS marker to set them as circle transiton pos
        CGPoint markerPoint =  annotation.position;
        x = markerPoint.x;
        y = markerPoint.y;

```
    circleSize = 10;
    radiusChange = 0;

    //Populate Same Values to next view to close
    VenueScreen.x = x;
    VenueScreen.y = y;

    VenueScreen.view.hidden = YES;
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(openVenueScreen) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    VenueScreen.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
    [self.view addSubview:VenueScreen.view];

}



//Circular transition to open Next view
-(void)openVenueScreen
{
    VenueScreen.view.hidden = NO;
    VenueScreen.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    VenueScreen.view.alpha = 0.9;
    self.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

    int rChange = 0; // Its doing proper masking while changing this value
    int radius = circleSize-rChange;

    CAShapeLayer *circleShapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];

    // Make a circular shape
    circleShapeLayer.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(x+radiusChange, y+radiusChange, 2.0*radius, 2.0*radius)
                                                       cornerRadius:radius].CGPath;
    radiusChange = radiusChange-10;

    // Configure the apperence of the circle
    [[VenueScreen.view layer] setMask:circleShapeLayer];

    //Start Transition
    circleSize = circleSize+10;

    if (circleSize > 480)
    {
        [[VenueScreen.view layer] setMask:nil];

        [timer invalidate]; //Stop titmer

        VenueScreen.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        VenueScreen.view.alpha = 1;

        //Populate to next view to close
        VenueScreen.radiusChange = radiusChange;
    }

}
```

***Close in Next View:***

```
//Close button Action
-(IBAction)DismissVenueScreen:(id)sender;
{
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(dismissVenueScreen) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    NSLog(@"close button clciked");
}

//Circular trasition to Close window
-(void)dismissVenueScreen
{
    int rChange = 0; // Its doing proper masking while changing this value
    int radius = circleSize-rChange;

    CAShapeLayer *circleShapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    // Make a circular shape
    circleShapeLayer.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(x+radiusChange,y+radiusChange, 2.0*radius, 2.0*radius)
                                                       cornerRadius:radius].CGPath;

    // Configure the apperence of the circle
    [[self.view layer] setMask:circleShapeLayer];
    self.view.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

    radiusChange = radiusChange+10;
    circleSize = circleSize-10;

    if (circleSize <= 0)
    {
        [timer invalidate]; //Stop titmer
        [[self.view layer] setMask:nil];
        [self.view removeFromSuperview];
        circleSize = 480;
    }

}
```